DataSource vs DataContext in Windows Forms DataGridView
Since .NET 7, Microsoft has improved the binding capabilities of Windows Forms to bring it closer to WPF and other XAML technologies: Using Command Binding in Windows Forms apps to go Cross-Platform - .NET Blog
So, among other things, the DataContext property was included in Windows Forms controls (Control.DataContext Property), similar to WPF (FrameworkElement.DataContext Property).
However, in controls such as DataGridView, which had the DataSource property (DataGridView.DataSource Property), the two properties began to coexist.
But what would be the difference between the two?

The DataSource is specific to a Control, the DataContext, as described in the documentation you linked, to a hierarchy of Controls bound to a Parent. When the default DataContext changes, because the Parent's DataContext has changed, the bound Controls drop their context entirely, and bind to the Parent's. Somewhat similar to the BindingContext, but fits the new(ish) data binding infrastructure (though the affected Controls are still responsible for the binding, eventually replacing / repopulating the existing internal source)
